# adding a virtual keyboard to a user input text box

Tags: python, authentication, user-input, virtual-keyboard

Hopefully my question that I am going to ask makes sense. I am trying to set up a login that when a user click on the User input text box a virtual keyboard will pop up for them to display their information into the required field. I pasted some pictures below to help get a proper visualization of what I am trying to do. Should I program a virtual keyboard from scratch and the implement the funtion? or is there a way to code in a virtual keyboard when user clicks in the userinput text box?

Before user logs  in

[image]

After user places mouse with the username and password input box and click the mouse a virtual keyboard is suppose to pop up.

[image]

Then when user clicks on password the same keyboard pops up allowing the user to enter in their password.

Comment: I don't know if you can start and control `Virtual keyboard` but long time ago was question where in answer I created keyboard attached to `Entry` - it was built using `Frame` with `Buttons` - and it was displayed when user clicked in `Entry`.

Comment: I found only example code which use Button to open Frame with keyboard and when you press buttons on keyboard then it send it to assigned Entry or Text: [GitHub: furas/python-examples/tkinter/keyboard.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/keyboard-keypad/keyboard-import/keyboard.py)

Comment: you can always try to open `Virtual Keyboard` using `subprocess` - maybe it will work.

Comment: I suggest just creating Your own keyboard since it will better fit visually and be contained in the same window

Comment: Thanks all for you help I will try each one and see which one works.